# What view/layout would work best for this Android fragment?

Tags: android, mobile, layout, view, fragment

I am trying to create a view like this in an Android fragment, and after doing a good amount of research, I am still unsure what the best way to go about doing this ***in a fragment***.

It appears to possibly need 2 different layouts, but I could also be very incorrect. I am new to Android and appreciate any help I can get.

[image: Attempted fragment layout]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a TabLayout probably with a viewpager inside.

The Shown fragment  has elements:

The circle is a custom progressdialog see:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progress_circle.htm

settings button is a floatingactionbutton -> i use(there are plenty though):

https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

The bottom layout can easily be achieved using a TableLayout.

Make the adjustments as per your need using these layouts.

Mind you, this is just one possible combination of layouts. There are plenty of arrangements using different layouts that you can make to achieve similar results.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of information I was hoping to receive. In your opinion, what would be the best way to separate the progress dialog and the TableLayout?

Comment: the progressdialog and the settings would themselves be in a nested horizontal linearlayout. This layout and the tablelayout would be placed inside a vertical linear layout and i would put some margin_top to the tablelayout view. -> try your own combinations which you feel comfortable with though